# Length of a float without trailing zeros (python)

Tags: python, precision, zero, trailing

I want to print the length of a float number without trailing zeros using python.
examples:

```
0.001000 >>> I want to get length=5

0.000100 >>> I want to get length=6

0.010000 >>> I want to get length=4
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a float to a str will automatically remove tailing zeros:

```
numbers = [0.0010000, 0.00000000100, 0.010000]

for number in numbers:
    number = '{0:.16f}'.format(number).rstrip("0")
    print(f"Converted to String: {str(number)} - Length: {len(str(number))}")
```

Results:

```
Converted to String: 0.001 - Length: 5
Converted to String: 0.000000001 - Length: 11
Converted to String: 0.01 - Length: 4
```

Comment: for numbers with more than 4 zeros, it shows '1e-05'
Example:
(str(float(0.00001))) >>> '1e-05'
(str(float(0.000001))) >>> '1e-06'
and then it will calculate the length wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
inp = '0.00100'
len(str(float(inp)))
```

Output:

This gives the length as 5

All the trailing zeroes will be removed.

Comment: for numbers with more than 4 zeros, it shows '1e-05'
Example:
(str(float(0.00001))) >>> '1e-05'
(str(float(0.000001))) >>> '1e-06'
and then it will calculate the length wrong